# Practice Linux Shell Scripting

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

My homework assignment is to write a shell script to read a "log.txt" and display its comments line by line. Each line should be prefixed by its line number.

Script I have so far:

```
path="/home/user/log.txt"
while i=read -r line
do
   echo "$line"
done < "$log_file"
```

Input file:

```
How are you
Where are you
```

Expected output:

```
1. How are you
2. Where are you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a counter, bump it up on every line, and print the counter with every line.

Also note fixes to set log_file, update to read command.

```
log_file="/home/user/log.txt"
line_no=0
while read -r line
do
   line_no=$((line_no+1))
   printf "%d. %s\n" $line_no "$line"
done < "$log_file"
```

One alternative to consider is to call the `nl` utility, which performs the exact task.

Answer (score 0):

> in python 3.8 this worked
>
> `count = 0
>   with open("log.txt") as file_in:
>       lines = []
>       for line in file_in:
>           lines.append(line)
>           print('{} {}'.format(count, line))
>           count +=1`

Answer (score 0):

Not a shellscript but some utility/program can do that.

```
grep -n . logfile.txt

cat -n logfile.txt

awk '{print NR" "$0}' logfile.txt
```

and many more...

Here is one using bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%d. %s\n' "$n" "$line"
  ((n++))
done < logfile.txt
```